# Create new folder & rename it & move all folders with special name into newly created folder

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have this code which is executed on user demand. It looks for any folder in `C:\test\test\test` that contains the word `part` and does some stuff to it.

```
set num=0
cd /d "C:\test\test\test"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *part* /b /ad /ODN ') do (

REM - New Funcations    
mkdir "tempgroup" && set name=%%a && ren "tempgroup" "!name:~0,-9!- GROUP VIDEO"
move %%a 

GOTO NEXT
)
```

I would like to expand the functionality but have spent a lot hours without getting the results I want.

First of all `%%a` = `2014-07-18 13h44m10s - Part 1`

1. To copy the folder name and rename `2014-07-18 13h44m10s - Part 1` to `2014-07-18 13h44m10s - GROUP VIDEO` with out making a temp directory `tempgroup`. The reason for this is to prevent the `tempgroup` folder from being created if the script is executed again.
2. To move all folders which contains the word `PART` into `2014-07-18 13h44m10s - GROUP VIDEO`

Here is a list of folders and how it would look:

`2014-07-18 13h44m10s - Part 1
 2014-07-18 13h45m10s - Part 2
 2014-07-18 13h46m20s - Part 3
 2014-07-18 13h47m32s - Part 4
 2014-07-18 13h48m10s - Part 5
 2014-07-18 13h48m20s - Part 6
 2014-07-18 13h48m30s - Part 7
 2014-07-18 13h48m40s - Part 8
 2014-07-18 13h49m50s - Part 9`

The above folder should be moved into this folder

`2014-07-18 13h44m10s - GROUP VIDEO`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following batch code **copies** all files (but not their subdirectories) in all subdirectories with **part** in name to a directory with **- GROUP VIDEOS** in name appended to date/time string of first directory with **part** in name.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "C:\test\test\test"
set GroupVideoDirectory=

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *part* /b /ad /ODN ') do (
    set "DirName=%%a"
    if "!GroupVideoDirectory!"=="" (
       set "GroupVideoDirectory=!DirName:~0,-9! - GROUP VIDEO"
       if not exist "!GroupVideoDirectory!" mkdir "!GroupVideoDirectory!"
    )
    copy /Y "%%a\*.*" "!GroupVideoDirectory!" >nul
)
endlocal
```

In other words all files from subdirectories like

- **2014-07-18 13h44m10s - Part 1**
- **2014-07-18 13h44m10s - Part 2**
- and so on

are copied to directory **2014-07-18 13h44m10s - GROUP VIDEO** created by this batch file if it does not already exist (for example from a previous run).

And the next batch code **moves** the files into the created directory and deletes the directories with **part** in name.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "C:\test\test\test"
set GroupVideoDirectory=

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *part* /b /ad /ODN ') do (
    set "DirName=%%a"
    if "!GroupVideoDirectory!"=="" (
       set "GroupVideoDirectory=!DirName:~0,-9! - GROUP VIDEO"
       if not exist "!GroupVideoDirectory!" mkdir "!GroupVideoDirectory!"
    )
    move /Y "%%a\*.*" "!GroupVideoDirectory!" >nul
    rd "%%a"
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Ok, it creates the folder however is it possible to `move` the folders into the newly created folder `GroupVideoDirectory`.

Comment: Trying this `move /Y "%%a" "!GroupVideoDirectory!" >nul`

Comment: Ok, with this change it moves the folder perfectly. `move /Y "%%a" "!GroupVideoDirectory!" >nul`

Answer (score 1):

Using the new data - Test this on copies of your folders.
It will also work if there are multiple groups of folders.

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\test\test\test"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *part* /b /ad') do (
   set "name=%%a" 
     if not "%%a"=="!name: - Part 1=!" set "groupfolder=!name:~0,20! - GROUP VIDEO"
   md "!groupfolder!" 2>nul
   move "%%a" "!groupfolder!" >nul
)
echo done
pause
```

Comment: Thank you, however the times of the folders will change and 2 will never be the same. I have update the original post.